# Solving a recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this, but the problem actually belongs to a programming assignment. This recursion is something I probably should know how to solve but Im having a bit of trouble with it.

Solve the recursion:

```
T(0) = 2;
T(n) = T(n-1) + 2;
```

Solution:

```
T(n) = 2(n+1)
```

Could someone please show me how they got to that solution?

*Please not that its not the main part of the assignment to solve this particular problem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd solve it as follows:

```
Assume that T(n) = a*n + b for some a and b.
T(0) = 2. So a * 0 + b = 2, thus b = 2.

T(n) = T(n-1) + 2, so 
a * n + b = (a * (n-1) + b) + 2 consequently
a * n + b = a * n - a + b + 2 and
0 = - a + 2, thus a = 2.

So we have T(n) = 2 * n + 2 = 2 (n+1).
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to figure out what is solution and then you can use induction, to prove it.

To figure solution is simple.

Value is previous value + 2.

```
2, 2+2, 2+2+2, 2+2+2+2, 2+2+2+2+2, ...
```

Use induction to prove:

```
T(0) = 2
T(n) = T(n-1) + 2;

Solution
T(n) = 2(n+1)

Proof:
T(n) = T(n-1) + 2 => 2((n-1)+1) + 2 = 2(n+1)

Check for n=0
2(0+1)=2

End of proof
```

Comment: The question was "how do you get to this solution", not "how do I prove this solution is true".

Comment: O, I should probably put more attention on how to figure out connection between 2,2+2,2+2+2,.. and multiplication.

Comment: The proof *is* the way to get the solution.

Comment: I'm amazed that induction isn't the accepted answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Answer (score 4):

Try writing out the first few values - it should then be obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately "Look at it, duh!" is rarely an appropriate proof in serious papers.

Comment: @Ignacio: true, but once you have the series in front of you, with actual numbers plugged in, it becomes much easier to formulate a proof (IMNVHO, at least)

Comment: I agree with Paul R, the poster did not ask for a proof but for a way to get the generating function. A proof could be done with e.g. mathematical induction.

Answer (score 4):

Take `T(5)`:

```
T(5)
  |
  +-> T(4) + 2
        |
        +-> T(3) + 2
              |
              +-> T(2) + 2 
                    |
                    +-> T(1) + 2
                          |
                          +-> T(0) + 2
                                |
                                +-> 2
```

Now count the number of `2`'s that are added together for `T(5)`.

Then try to figure out how many `2`'s would be added for `T(n)`.

Answer (score 4):

It's an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) with <strike>ratio</strike> common difference 2.

The first term is `T[0] = 2` and the <strike>ratio</strike> common difference is `r = 2` so the `n + 1`th term (`n + 1`th because there are `n + 1` numbers in `0, 1, 2, ..., n`) is `T[0] + r*(n + 1 - 1) = 2 + 2*n = 2*(n + 1)`.

No guessing required, just recognize it as an arithmetic progression.

Comment: changed ratio to common difference as ratio is used for geometric progressions, not arithmetic progressions.

Comment: I am amazed you're the only one naming this progression for what it is... if it had begun at `T(6)` a number of people would have clueless it seems.

Answer (score 3):

Each time `n` decreases by one, `2` is added. This gives a variable term of `2n`. Since T(0) is fixed at `2`, this gives a constant term of `2`. Adding them together gives `2n + 2`, or `2(n + 1)`.

Comment: It decreases in the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty straightforward to solve by hand as the other answers point out, but in case it's ever useful, Mathematica is pretty good solving [recurrence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) like this.

Evaluating

```
RSolve[{T[0] == 2, T[n] == T[n-1] + 2}, T[n], n]
```

returns

```
{{T[n] -> 2 (1 + n)}}
```

It can, for example, find the closed form of the nth Fibonacci number as well:

```
RSolve[{F[1] == 1, F[2] == 1, F[n] == F[n-1] + F[n-2]}, F[n], n] //FunctionExpand
```

returns

```
{{F[n] -> (((1 + Sqrt[5])/2)^n - (2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n*Cos[n*Pi])/Sqrt[5]}}
```